# Push object to array of objects on click

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a `vue.js` app that has objects being rendered in a single list with two columns as shown below:
[image]

When I click on the "X" on the object, I get the following return:
[image]

The method is shown below:

```
remove(x) {
    console.log(this.$data.list.selected[x]);
    console.log(this.$data.list.available);
    console.log(x);
},
```

The `this.$data.list.selected[x]` is the object in the left column, and the array of objects is in `this.$data.list.available`.

What would be the best way for me to remove the object inside my method and then push it to the end of the array in `this.$data.list.available`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) the item to remove it from `this.$data.list.selected[]`, and [`push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) it into `this.$data.list.available[]`:

```js
this.$data.list.available.push(...this.$data.list.selected.splice(x, 1))
```